# r - prefixing specific column titles in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

Hello absolute noob here so apologies if I don't know exactly what you are telling me first without a bit of a google to help me understand!

I have a data frame with 6 cols, four of which contain the word qPCR, i.e

sample..id...mean_qPCR..sd_qPCR..sem_qPCR..total_qPCR

`Data <- data.frame(
    sample = sample(1:10),
    id = sample(1:10),
    mean_qPCR =sample(1:10),
    sd_qPCR = sample(1:10),
    sem_qPCR = sample(1:10),
    total_qPCR = sample(1:10))`

I have multiple dataframes like this looking at different genes so I want to prefix the columns with qPCR in them with the gene name, i.e

sample..id...gene_mean_qPCR..gene_sd_qPCR..gene_sem_qPCR..gene_total_qPCR

`Data <- data.frame(
    sample = sample(1:10),
    id = sample(1:10),
    gene_mean_qPCR = sample(1:10),
    gene_sd_qPCR = sample(1:10),
    gene_sem_qPCR = sample(1:10),
    gene_total_qPCR = sample(1:10)
    )`

I had thought about using rename, but could only change one column title at a time. was then thinking grepl and rename might do it, but not sure how to implement these together?

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: where do you get the gene names?

Comment: @Sotos The gene name I would be adding manually I guess, the only place it could currently be taken from is the name of the dataframe, but there are other names in there too

Comment: Ok. The best thing to do in order to help us help you is to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and expected outcome.

Comment: Something like this @Sotos?, thanks for your help by the way, as I said, pretty new to r and first post to stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste0` to add leading genes at required columns. What the below piece of code does is that it identifies (`grepl`) which columns have the word 'qPCR' and adds the string 'gene_' using `paste0`.

```
names(Data)[grepl('qPCR', names(Data))] <- paste0('gene_', names(Data)[grepl('qPCR', names(Data))])

head(Data)
#  sample id gene_mean_qPCR gene_sd_qPCR gene_sem_qPCR gene_total_qPCR
#1     10  3              4            7             8               1
#2      5  1              2            5             3               7
#3      6 10              9           10            10               9
#4      2  5              6            3             9               8
#5      4  4              1            4             5               6
#6      9  6              3            1             4               4
```